# How to introduce a tab after number in a section title?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like to have a fixed distance from the beginning of the section number to the section title. Visually, I expect all section and subsection numbers and titles to line up vertically as if they were justified to the left in invisible two columns. However, the default behaviour of `titlesec` is to add fixed distance after the end of the number so I get numbers justified to the left, but titles are a fixed distance from the end of the number.

I have experimented a bit with `parbox`, which gives me the visual effect I am after, but I think this creates a parbox on the title rather than a number and there's some vertical translation, which I tried to tackle manually with `raisebox`, but quite ineffectively.

My MWE:

```latex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\raisebox{0pt}{\parbox{20pt}{\thesection}}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\raisebox{-0.25pt}{\parbox{20pt}{\thesubsection}}}{0pt}{}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate some advice on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `\makebox` instead of `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\makebox[20pt][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\makebox[20pt][l]{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

[image]